# Summernote icons are not loading after upload static files to aws

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, summernote

I uploaded my static files to aws s3 buckets. font awesome css files are not loading. And also in admin page also loads fine.but icons in the summernote are not working in admin page. Picture of a admin page.Error in console is `"The server respond with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"`  [image: this is a screenshot of a admin page of my project] help in advance thanks ,
Dinindu.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to you. After login into AWS console go [here](https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/mjspace/?region=ap-northeast-1&tab=permissions)

In CORN settings add the bellow code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: this didn't work do you have another option

Comment: you can add these in header file 
`<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.1/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: @ Jafoor I added it to my index.html but it didn’t work.I think because of it’s
not the html file of admin page.So do you know how can i find the html
file of admin page.

Comment: @ Jafoor Do you have json format of this xml code.cause I think It will work

Comment: `[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "Content-*",
            "Authorization"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]`
You can use this. Sorry for the code formation.